# When using scrollTo ListView does not refresh, but when manually scrolling it refreshes

Tags: android, android-listview

I have different colors for different lines in the ListView, by setting the color of textbox depending on the line number (in getView() of Adapter). Now when I manually scroll the ListView upwards the correct color is displayed in the bottom lines that get revealed. But when I use scrollTo, this doesnot happen, all lines revealed have the same color (they are not updated).

Has anybody faced this issue? This seems baffling!

Answer (score 6):

`ListView#scrollTo` doesn't scroll the list contents. (It's a standard View method, and not specific to lists at all: it scrolls the ListView view itself.)

Instead, try using `ListView#setSelectionFromTop(0, int y)` to scroll.

API 19+ has a `ListView#scrollListBy(int y)` method if you're programming for KitKat and up.

Comment: I am looking for the same solution....scrollTo doesn't update the listview content..And using setSelectionFromTop doesn't scroll the listview....I have the 'y' value but I don't know which position to scroll...Any clue?

Comment: If you use `setSelectionFromTop(int posittion, int y)` with a position of 0, the `ListView` will move to the top of your list. The `y` value is the distance from the top edge of that ListView item. (You may have to negate your `y` value.)

Comment: I tried `setSelectionFromTop(int posittion, int y)` with the position as 0, but the list remains at the first position(does not scroll) irrespective of the `y` value ....

Answer (score 0):

In our project `ListView#setSelectionFromTop(0, int y)` does not have any effect. So we hacked this in compat-style:

```
class Hacks {

static {
    Method trackMotionScroll = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        try {
            trackMotionScroll = AbsListView.class
                    .getDeclaredMethod("trackMotionScroll", int.class, int.class);
            trackMotionScroll.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Exceptions.crash(e);
        }
    }
    listViewTrackMotionScroll = trackMotionScroll;
}

public static void scrollListBy(ListView listView, int y) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        listView.scrollListBy(y);
    } else {
        try {
            listViewTrackMotionScroll.invoke(listView, -y, -y);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Exceptions.crash(e);
        }
    }
}
}
```