# Android development: Where to report bugs in the android development environment?

Tags: android

I am developing an app using ListView, and I am facing the problem which I have mentioned in this link: [When using scrollTo ListView does not refresh, but when manually scrolling it refreshes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923055/android-listview-when-using-scrollto-listview-does-not-refresh-but-when-manual).

Where can I report this bug in the Android development environment so that this issue can be fixed, and I can develop my app the way I want it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to this : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list. This has a complete list of known issues and you could log new ones as well.

Comment: Thanks man!  (and adding this just so that I can post this comment - for some reason comments must be at least 15 chars in length - its quite irritating!)

Comment: Note: If your bug is already registered, you only need to "star" it at the bottom of the issue to "vote" for it to be fixed asap.